# VSCode not responding after installing it on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, 22.04, sudo, deb

I am a new Ubuntu user running Ubuntu 22.04.03 on a dual booted X1 Carbon 7th gen. I have attempted to install a variety of versions of VSCode (1.80, 1.81) in a variety of way (apt, snap, apt with downloaded .deb file). Each time I am able to successfully install and run VSCode, however it immediately freezes before any input and stops responding. When running with `--verbose` enabled this is a lot of information, but what may be helpful from it is the following:

```
[33236:0816/192135.291767:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(247)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[33272:0816/192135.392406:WARNING:sandbox_linux.cc(380)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```